# Flex e4x filter out children

Tags: apache-flex, filter, e4x

I'm trying to filter my xml so that the childnodes are not displayed.
This xml will then be used as a dataprovider for my advanceddatagrid.
Given this XML :

```
<item text="folder1" display="true">
  <item text="folder2" display="true">
    <item text="node" display="true">
      <item display="false">
        <property1>val1</property1>
        <property2>val2</property2>
      </item>
    </item>
  </item>
</item>
```

What I want is an XML with only the nodes that have the property display set to true.
So, the resulting XML should be:

```
<item text="folder1" display="true">
  <item text="folder2" display="true">
    <item text="node" display="true">
    </item>
  </item>
</item>
```

When I try `trace(data.item.(@display == 'true'));` every node is still displayed, even the ones with display false..

Any help would be appreciated ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, this is how I solved it now :

```
var childNodes:XMLList = new XMLList(data.descendants("item").(@display == 'false'));
for ( var i:int = childNodes.length() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    delete childNodes[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because of the format of that XML.

All of the item elements under folder1 are child nodes of folder1. Since it has 
display="true", then the trace will display all of its children.

Anyone else, is this XML formatted correctly to do the search?