# E4X - Retrieve element without retrieving its children

Tags: javascript, xml, e4x

Given a XML object, how could I retrieve only the root element without retrieving together its children?

E.g.:

```
var exampleXml = new XML("<parent name="Teste"><child/><child2/><child3/></parent>");
exampleXml.getOnlyRootElement(); //<parent name="Teste"/>
```

I've found this solution - [Flex e4x filter out children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304134/flex-e4x-filter-out-children) - but I didn't like it very much. Is there a better one?

PS: I'm running javascript in an windows app using SpiderMonkey.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the child reference to an empty XMLList.

```
 exampleXML.setChildren(new XMLList(''));
```

If you want to preserve the original XML object, make a deep copy first

```
 childFreeXML = exampleXML.copy().setChildren(new XMLList(''));
```